Math trauma and getting back to recreational math (soft question)
I would like to hear from mathematicians here if they share traumas similar to mine. I was doing fairly well in math until university. I had even won several medals from the Mathematical Olympiad. (I had been to the Informatics Olympiad too). However, I absolutely hated school exams. Yes, I am bad at trivial questions that is not theoretical and especially numerical calculations. I enjoyed discovering new solutions, new proves, and, at times, inventing wheels, tho.
Recently, I watched a TV programme discussing developments on Millennium Prize Problems and somehow I just couldn’t stop my math itch again. I, by no means, would like to be a professional/serious mathematician now, but it reminded me of my old good days. I could be sitting there and staring at a problem/proof for hours or even days back then. It was fun.
I am thinking about getting back into recreational math (is that what it’s called?). Just to have fun. But, I don’t have a clue where to get started. I would appreciate anyone sharing ideas, suggestions.
Thank you!

Many of the posts here have a recreational feel, at least.  Maybe you could try to work on some of those.  No pressure attached...work on the problems you like when the mood strikes you.

I think the comment above is a very healthy approach. MSE is currently my only real recreational outlet right now. I wonder if someone has some amateurish/undergrad/highschool accessible journals that one could subscribe to... I would love some recommendations. Reading math and doing math aren't the same but both seem to scratch my itches.

I never know how to answer these types of soft questions on MSE whether an idea counts as a "comment" or "answer".There is certainly no rule stopping you from going through a textbook and working through the exercises at your own pace i.e., not part of a university course.

@lulu Good idea. Ta!

I found this site to be an excellent place for finding random problems to solve. Solving problems that are slightly beyond my current ability somehow helps me calm down and reset. Writing well structured answers feels like I'm writing a publication about my findings! It's a miniaturized research process that I find hard to give up on. Use this site as a way to research your interests!

Per the Help Center, questions which seek to start a conversation, or which don't have an authoritative correct answer, are not on topic here.  Math SE is not a social networking site---it is a repository of questions and answers.

@Mike Thank you. Tbh, I’m thinking about picking up my abandoned Abstract Algebra first. Any recommendations on textbooks?

@XanderHenderson Would it be a better idea if I reframe it as asking for advice on recreational math?

r/math and r/mathematics on reddit have many questions like this.  I find those sites helpful, although I see why someone might prefer to ask the MSE audience.

You'll probably be able to generate a conversation in our chat rooms as well. You'll be able to find some sympathy/empathy in chat.

Israel Herstein 's Topics in Algebra is pretty great/standard.

I wonder if someone has some amateurish/undergrad/highschool accessible journals --- See the freely available old issues of Pi Mu Epsilon Journal & Quantum & Mathematical Spectrum whose links are given in this MSE answer.
